# How is "egg=" used in "pip install -e"?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Trying to test editable installs out and I'm not sure how to interpret the results.

I intentionally made a typo in the `egg=` portion but it was still able to locate the egg without any help from me:

```
root@6be8ee41b6c9:/# pip3 install -e git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git      
Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

root@6be8ee41b6c9:/# pip3 install -e git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git#egg=
Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git#egg=', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

root@6be8ee41b6c9:/# pip3 install -e git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git#egg=e
Obtaining e from git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git#egg=e
  Cloning https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git to /src/e
  Running setup.py (path:/src/e/setup.py) egg_info for package e produced metadata for project name clientapp. Fix your #egg=e fragments.
Installing collected packages: clientapp
  Found existing installation: ClientApp 0.7
    Can't uninstall 'ClientApp'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Running setup.py develop for clientapp
Successfully installed clientapp

root@6be8ee41b6c9:/# pip3 freeze
asn1crypto==0.24.0
-e git+https://gitlab.com/jame/clientapp.git@5158712c426ce74613215e61cab8c21c7064105c#egg=ClientApp
cryptography==2.6.1
entrypoints==0.3
keyring==17.1.1
keyrings.alt==3.1.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
PyGObject==3.30.4
pyxdg==0.25
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.12.0
```

So if I could mess the egg name up so bad, why is it considered an error to either leave it blank or set to something empty

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support "*The “project name” component of the URL suffix egg=<project name> is used by pip in its dependency logic to identify the project*". It must be `#egg=name` or `#egg=name-version`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+egg+name+version

Comment: @phd Very interesting information but my question is why I'm seeing the above behavior. Should I interpret "prior to pip downloading and analyzing the metadata" to mean that the name doesn't ultimately matter if there's a `setup.py` ? If so why not have some sort of randomized default? Why does it have to be specified if there are cases where it can be actual random strings and still work?

Comment: Hard to answer, maybe raise this as an issue on _pip_'s bug tracker and get an accurate answer from the developers themselves. -- My guess, the egg name matters if the project is a dependency of another project. For example in a case where one wants to install `A` from PyPI and `Z` from _git_, but _Z_ is a dependency of _A_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is outdated notation. Nowadays one should use the following notation whenever possible:

```
python -m pip install 'ProjecName @ git+https://example.local/repository.git@1.3.1'
```

---

My guess, the name matters if the project is a dependency of another project. For example in a case where one wants to install `A` from *PyPI* and `Z` from *git*, but `Z` is a dependency of `A`.

```
python -m pip install 'A' 'git+https://example.local/Z.git#egg=Z'
```

or with new notation:

```
python -m pip install 'A' 'Z @ git+https://example.local/repository.git
```

Comment: Do they allow Q&A in their GH issues or is it supposed to be just for bugs? I mean I guess I can try to find their mailing list or something.

Comment: The behavior described in the question kind of looks like somewhat of a bug to me. If you explicitly want the _Alpha_ egg, but get _Bravo_ instead (because for whatever reason that's what is in the repository), then _pip_ should probably fail with a message. -- Anyway, _Q&A_ on GitHub should be okay, you are also quite likely to get some feedback in this [forum](https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/14), if you don't want to raise a bug yet.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and award this and accept the answer since the bounty is in "use it or lose it" territory and this is answer that's gotten the closest to answering the original question.

Comment: For me I got message which suggests which #egg value to use:

"Discarding git+https://****@github.com/arelle/arelle.git@master#egg=arelle: Requested arelle-release from git+https://****@github.com/arelle/arelle.git@master#egg=arelle has inconsistent name: **expected 'arelle', but metadata has 'arelle-release'**"

Specifically, match the value in the `pyproject.toml` [`[project].name` property, which was `name = "arelle-release"`](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/blob/master/pyproject.toml#L6)

Answer (score 1):

`egg=` is the name that's used when uninstalling unpackaged libraries that's installed from a VCS repository, and the name that's used by the dependency resolver when searching for dependant packages.

If you don't care about those two use cases, they can essentially be set to anything.

> it found the egg via setup.py

It didn't find the egg via setup.py, pip found the setup.py and set the egg name for the setup.py install to whatever you specified. When you're installing from a VCS, there is no package, so there's no egg name configured, `egg=` configures the installation as if it has been installed with a package with that egg name.

Comment: How did it find the correct egg name? Check my `pip3 freeze` output, it was able to figure out somehow that the real egg name is `ClientApp` even when I set `egg=` to gibberish. The `pip3 install` output also tells me to fix what I gave it for an egg name since apparently it could tell that wasn't the correct egg name.